# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context on line 50

Tags: php, fatal-error

I am doing sharing form and I can´t find out the problem. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php 
        if ($hlaska)
            echo('<p>' . htmlspecialchars($hlaska) . '</p>');

        $vasemail = (isset($_POST['vasemail'])) ? $_POST['vasemail'] : '';
        $email = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
        $predmet = (isset($_POST('predmet')) ? $_POST['predmet'] : '';
        $zprava = (isset($_POST['zprava'])) ? $_POST['zprava'] : '';
?>
```

This is code about line 50. Line 50 is starting with $predmet

If I comment or delete all code contenting something with $predmet it works as it should. $predmet is in English $subject FYI.

Comment: now u have 2 solutions given below, test it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because of this `$_POST('predmet')`

This should be:

```
$predmet = (isset($_POST['predmet'])) ? $_POST['predmet'] : '';
```

You are getting the Fatal Error because this `$_POST('predmet')` consider here as a method which is wrong this is **Super Global**.

Comment: Waah Bhai. *Umda*

Comment: @NanaPartykar: :)

Comment: Thank you, didn´t realise it.

Comment: @pandik70: glad to help u